# Simple.Data and Oracle Managed Provider cannot open connection

Tags: .net, oracle, simple.data

I am trying to use Simple.Data with Oracle Managed Provider using nuget package from https://github.com/SimonH/Simple.Data.Oracle.

I have following code:

```
var db = Database.OpenNamedConnection("ManagedOdpOracle");
db.Open();
```

The entry in app.config is like this:

```
<add name="ManagedOdpOracle" connectionString="Data Source=ora11;User id=User;Password=pwd" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

I cannot make it work, every time I get exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: connectionName
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: did you fix it? i got the error